# Alfresco Share: Admin override for read-only form fields

Tags: xml, forms, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am looking for a way to set custom forms in Share to be read-only for general users, but to allow them to be edited by administrator level users. At the moment I am using the "read-only" = true argument in my form field in the share-config-custom.xml, which achieves the first part of my goal. However, I'm still looking for a way which the admin could override this and make changes to those form fields, if necessary.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Marcus

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create your custom control for this.How to create custom control is explained on below link.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/dev-extensions-share-form-controls.html

In this custom ftl you need to determine whether the user is admin on not that you can check on below link.

https://community.alfresco.com/thread/185737-how-to-check-if-admin-in-ftl

### Bit more information on this

There are two things using which you can make control ready-only.First by giving ready-only.ftl as a field template and second is by adding read-only as true in form configuration...